# how to add current date to sql database using Validate()

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have C# programme that takes values from textBoxes and add it to sql database using `validate()` method on the save button in the BindingNavigator

```
    private void tableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        this.Validate();
        this.tableTiryaqBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.tiryaqDataSet);           
    }
```

But I need to add the current `date` to date column without taking it from `DateTimePicker`.
the date column don't allow `null`, I tried this code

```
    private void tableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        this.Validate();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table(date) VALUES(@date)", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        this.tableTiryaqBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.tiryaqDataSet);           
    }
```

but it gives me null Exception on the date column !! so anybody know how to do it ?

Comment: Is the `insert` statement correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer press the arrow beside the `Dataset` then open `Dataset.Desiner.cs`.
Search for the column you want, (here is `DATE`) and find the `Default Value` line.
here you can put you code like this

`private static System.DateTime columndate_defaultValue = System.DateTime.Now;`

you will find this line without `defaultValue = System.DateTime.Now;` then you add it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have permissions then you can add `GetDate()` as default value in column. It will automatically put current date in date column

EDIT:

You don't need to send date from your code now, DB server will insert current date in date column on insert. If you can't change parameters list and you have to send it then you can send it as null and declare your parameter like `@date datetime = NULL`

```
 SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table(date) VALUES('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "')", con);
```

Comment: it also gives me `System.Data.NoNullAllowedException: Column 'date' does not allow nulls.`

Comment: where to add this line `@date datetime = NULL` ?

Comment: OK, looks a bit strange req. How many columns do you have in your table?

Answer (score 0):

alter DB table itself and define GETDATE() as default value for Date column

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the type of your parameter:

```
SqlParameter parameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
parameter.Value = DateTime.Now;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Put a break point at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`. Which value has the parameter? If it's not null, the preblem is in an other part of your code, like the `INSERT`. Check the table and column names, try to execute the query directly to the db